# Split numeric column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have SQL-query which grouped owners and their statuses from two tables:

```
select value, count(distinct owner_id) as owners, account.status
from accounts_login_history
left join accounts on accounts.id = accounts_login_history.owner_id
where date >= '2020-02-01'
and owner_type = 1
group by value, accounts.status
```

Output:

[image]

How I should change my query for split `status` column into all categorical values (status have 5 unique values)?

[image]

I use postgresql.

Thank you!

Comment: Edit your question so it is obvious where the columns come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres is best accomplished using `filter`:

```
select value, count(distinct owner_id) as owners,
       max(a.status) filter (where status = 1) as status_1,
       max(a.status) filter (where status = 2) as status_2,
       max(a.status) filter (where status = 3) as status_3,
       max(a.status) filter (where status = 4) as status_4,
       max(a.status) filter (where status = 5) as status_5
from accounts_login_history alh left join
     accounts a 
     on accounts.id = alh.owner_id
where date >= '2020-02-01' and
      owner_type = 1
group by value;
```

This returns `null`s for the missing values rather than `0`.  You can -- of course -- use `coalesce()` to change this to `0`.  However, I prefer `null`s.

Comment: Thank you! I edited your query a bit cause I would get how much there are accounts with each status: `select value, count(distinct owner_id) as owners,
       count(distinct owner_id) filter (where status = 1) as status_1,
       ...
       count(distinct owner_id) filter (where status = 5) as status_5
from accounts_login_history alh left join
     accounts a 
     on a.id = alh.owner_id
where date >= '2020-02-01' and
      owner_type = 1
group by value;`